# How to copy MP3 files from my PC to my iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mp3

How to copy MP3 files from my PC to my iphone? I have many Mp3 on my PC but  some Mp3s I want to copy in iphone to listen from iphone. How to do that? I'm having itunes account and itunes software on my PC but unable to copy MP3s to iphone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In iTunes under the **File** menu choose **Add to Library...** and select the songs you want to add to iTunes. When iTunes is done adding the files, sync your iPhone with iTunes on your PC.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I've done the same but my copied songs are not showing when i click on iPod icon in my iphone.

Comment: When your iPhone is attached, in iTunes click on the name of your iPhone in the left column. A series of tabs (sort of) will appear on the right, with with "Summary" tab selected by default. Click on the "Music" tab, check the "Sync Music" checkbox, and choose "Entire music library." Sync again (the button in the lower-right) and you should be set.

Comment: There's also a way to do it wirelessly: http://osxdaily.com/2012/12/09/add-music-to-iphone-or-ipod-wirelessly-without-syncing-itunes/

Comment: Are you sure that iTunes "copies" the files and doesn't modify the original files in the original location?

Comment: @djangofan I can't say for sure now, iTunes has a changed a lot in the 4 years since my answer.

Comment: Dreadful usability again from Apple. Cannot believe drag and drop wasn't sufficient.

Comment: Note that to all appearances, this fails silently. It may take over 24 hours for the album to actually appear on the phone. This is due to Apple's fundamental UI principle of inflicting maximum pain on the user, but only when absolutely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

With Catalina macOS (1.15+) iTunes is gone.

You will need to open **Music** application & click under the **File** and chose **Import...**

After the mp3 files are imported; you can sync music via **Finder** by clicking on your iPhone's icon within a Finder's sidebar. Then click Music & check *Sync music onto My iPhone*.