# Is there any way to transfer mp3 files from PC to iPhone without uploading them to the cloud first?

Tags: itunes, mp3

When I do a search for how to transfer mp3 files from PC to iPhone I invariably come across answers that mention iTunes. E.g:

[How to copy MP3 files from my PC to my iphone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/how-to-copy-mp3-files-from-my-pc-to-my-iphone)

My guess is that what's happening here is that the files are first getting uploaded to the cloud and from there they are downloaded to iPhone. Is that correct? If not, then why does one have to use iTunes?

I have very large amount of data. Is there any way to transfer files directly from PC to iPhone via USB *without them being uploaded to the cloud first*? The files could even be confidential and so I don't want to upload them to the cloud.

Comment: an app like ifunbox could do that. Just find a folder with other mp3 files and put yours there too.

Comment: The linked question depends entirely on USB, not the cloud at all.

Comment: ...in other words iTunes is the preferred and easiest way to transfer audio files (Music, etc.) from your PC to the phone. The "cloud" is not involved it goes directly between the PC and the iPhone via the USB cable.

Comment: Ok. So then why can't I drag and drop the folder? I don't want to have to download and install iTunes now for this.

Comment: I think the issue is MacOS and Windows have fundamentally different file system, that makes it impossible to just drag'n drop from a Windows machine onto an Apple device, thus requiring an additional software to do the extra file manipulation. :/